# Json array to json php

Tags: php, arrays, json, laravel, model

I have the following json. the retailer_info property is array of 1 element.

```
{
"data": {
    "user": {
        "id": 18626,
        "first_name": "Sip",
        "last_name": "Gemmayzeh",
        "retailer_info": [
            {
                "id": 231,
                "retailer_id": 18626,
                "store_id": 344,
                "created_at": "2018-02-26 09:32:58",
                "updated_at": "2018-02-26 09:32:58"
            }
        ],
        "op_city": {
            "id": 1,
            "ref": "Beirut",
            "currency_id": 5,
            "currency": {
                "id": 5,
                "symbol": "USD"
            }
        },
        "team_lead": null,
        "op_city_languages": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "locale": "en",
                "name": "English"
            }
        ]
    }
},
"errors": false
}
```

I want to convert the array to single json object as following

```
 "retailer_info": {
                "id": 231,
                "retailer_id": 18626,
                "store_id": 344,
                "created_at": "2018-02-26 09:32:58",
                "updated_at": "2018-02-26 09:32:58"
            },
```

My laravel code is simply getting the model like this

```
$user = User::with('retailerInfo', 'opCity', ...)->get();
```

I tried the following but did not work. it kept the array as is.

```
$user->retailerInfo = $user->retailerInfo[0];
```

Comment: "Did not work" *how/why?*

Comment: Can you please var dump the `$user` value after retrieve the model?

Comment: I suggest creating a class that contains all fields that you desire to expose (via JSON) and then serialize that class instance. that a) gives you control over what you want to expose and b) helps keeping it understandable what you are doing.

Answer (score 0):

```
$user->retailerInfo = reset($user->retailerInfo);
```

This should do the trick for you. I had faced a similar issue that i wanted to "un-nest" an array this helped me solve it.

Answer (score 0):

Sound strange because `->get()` always returns a Collection
You should use `->first()` or `->firstOrFail()` to retrive only one element.
Or you can call `->each($callback)` to apply a callback on each element.
Use [] brackets in with()

```
$user = User::with(['retailerInfo', 'opCity', ...])->firstOrFail();
dd($user->retailerInfo->first());
```

or

```
User::with(['retailerInfo', 'opCity', ...])->each(function($user) {
    dump($user->retailerInfo->first());
});
```